# POST request method via a call to GET, SlimPHP, RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, http, rest, slim

Tools I'm using: Slim Framework & RedBeanPHP

I'm studying this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-slim-rest/ and especially this method:

```
// handle POST requests to /articles
$app->post('/articles', function () use ($app) 
{    
try 
{   // get and decode JSON request body
        $request = $app->request();
        $body = $request->getBody();
        $input = json_decode($body); 

        // store article record
        $article = R::dispense('articles');
        $article->title = (string)$input->title;
        $article->url = (string)$input->url;
        $article->date = (string)$input->date;
        $id = R::store($article);    

        // return JSON-encoded response body
        $app->response()->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode(R::exportAll($article));

} catch (Exception $e) {
        $app->response()->status(400);
        $app->response()->header('X-Status-Reason', $e->getMessage());
}
});
```

I run the application or refresh/enter whatever you like, but don't see any reporting of POST in my console as in the article?

I'm expecting to see: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-slim-rest/#f5

in my console.

Instead I get: http://acookson.org/?attachment_id=1221

It's a GET request method right? So how does the author trick the browser into reporting it as a POST request without the use of a HTML form?

With this line I hear you say:

```
// get and decode JSON request body
$request = $app->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
$input = json_decode($body);
```

Well I'm copying the article like for like and nope - nothing added to the database either.

I can acheive something similar with CURL

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"id": "3", "title": "Programming with C++", "url":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/programming\/C++","date":"2013-01-10"}' http://example.localhost/articles
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2013 08:52:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2
Content-Length: 116
Content-Type: application/json

POST
[{"id":3,"title":"Programming with C++","url":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/programming\/C++","date":"2013-01-10"}]
```

with row 3 added to my database:

```
mysql> select * from articles\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 1
title: Search and integrate Google+ activity streams with PHP applications
url: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-googleplusphp/index.html
date: 2012-07-10
*************************** 2. row ***************************
id: 2
title: Getting Started with Zend Server CE
url: http://devzone.zend.com/1389/getting-started-with-zend-server-ce/
date: 2009-03-02
*************************** 3. row ***************************
id: 3
title: Programming with C++
url: http://www.google.com/programming/C++
date: 2013-01-10
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you have asked.

> "It's a GET request method right? So how does the author trick the
>   browser into reporting it as a POST request without the use of a HTML
>   form?"

Yes, you are right, the author haven't mentioned anything on how he is posting the data, like using a HTML form.

Author might have used a rest client plugin in his browser. Perhaps a similar [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/).

> I can achieve something similar with CURL

Sure you can.

Actually your problem is not within the context slim or php.

So you might need to clarify the problem in more detail with corrected tags.